# Spring MessageSource.getMessage with arguments containing International characters showing up as ISO-8859 encoded characters

Tags: spring-messaging

I am using Spring Message with placeholders to create an email message.  The arguments for the placeholders contain International Characters.  Once the email body text is set using the `getMessage()` method with message, arguments and Locale and email is sent, the email received has the placeholder values with ISO-8859 chars.  How to ensure that the UTF-8 encoded Arguments are preserved while getting replaced in the message property.

Return property bundle:

```
    @Bean
    public MessageSource emailProps() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new 
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:props/Email");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }
```

MailSender.java

```
    @Autowired
    private MessageSource emailProps;

    public void send(String to, String language,String name, String org_name) throws MessagingException {
        //org_name has values like "GmbH (Süd) München"

        //some code here

        MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper=new MimeMessageHelper(message, 
        MimeMessageHelper.MULTIPART_MODE_MIXED_RELATED, "UTF-8");

        //helper.setFrom, helper.setTo....

        helper.setText(emailProps.getMessage("security.email.body", new Object[] {name,org_name}, 
        Locale.GERMAN)+emailProps.getMessage("email.footer", null, Locale.GERMAN), true);

        //remaining part of the code

    }
```

In the Email org_name comes up as "GmbH (SÃ¼d) MÃ¼nchen".

Question: What should I do so that the UTF-8 encoded argument values are retained as-is?  I have the argument values coming from DB and have verified that they do retain the encoding till the step before they are written into the message body.